# Convert double array to QByteArray

Tags: qt, serialization, arrays

What is the best way to convert a double array (double*) to a QByteArray ?

I have the size of the array.
I thought of converting each double to a QByteArray and then append all the arrays to a big QByteArray.

For the other way, well maybe parse the data to many QByteArrays (one for each double) and convert them to double.

I don't know which QByteArray method to use for an efficient parsing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `double* da` and size of that array `s` you may use the following:

```
QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(da),s*sizeof(double))
```